# I'm writing some Solidity and this error keeps poppping up

Tags: blockchain, solidity

This is my code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.7.2/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.7.2/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.7.2/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.7.2/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Alchemy is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage {
using Counters for Counters.Counter;

```
Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
uint256 MAX_SUPPLY = 10000;

constructor() ERC721("Blaze", "BLZ") {}

function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public {
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    require(tokenId <= MAX_SUPPLY, "All NFTs have been minted")
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
}

// The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
    internal
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
{
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
}

function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
    super._burn(tokenId);
}

function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
    public
    view
    override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
    returns (string memory)
{
    return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
}

function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
    public
    view
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    returns (bool)
{
    return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
}
```

}

On '_tokenIdCounter.increment();' it keeps making a ParserError but I don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In `safeMint()` function, you missed to put semicolon after `require` statement at line 19.

Your original smart contract:

```
...
uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
require(tokenId <= MAX_SUPPLY, "All NFTs have been minted") // <- Error is here!
_tokenIdCounter.increment();
_safeMint(to, tokenId);
...
```

Correct way to solve your issue:

```
...
uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
require(tokenId <= MAX_SUPPLY, "All NFTs have been minted"); // <- Add semicolon
_tokenIdCounter.increment();
_safeMint(to, tokenId);
...
```